# Drupal 8: set (sub) fields of the address field optional (not required)

Tags: 8, entities

I need an address field that allow the user to encode only a country **OR** a country with some other fields he could choose freely.

I other words, I need an address field without any required field.

To do so, I have tried to alter the widget as explained in some tutorials:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  $field_definition = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field_definition->getType() == 'address') {
    $element['name_block']['name_line']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $element['street_block']['thoroughfare']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $element['locality_block']['dependent_locality']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $element['locality_block']['locality']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $element['locality_block']['administrative_area']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $element['locality_block']['postal_code']['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
```

}

Unfortunately, the $element variable is not yet populated with the subfields...

Comment: Hi @Baud. Were you able to make address fields optional based on a specific field in custom module for D8?

Comment: Just use the last version of the date module. In the settings of the date field you want to add to a content type, you will find all the needed options to make some fields optional.

Comment: Date or address? And I want to make the address fields optional based on the value of another field in the custom form.

Comment: Sorry, you should read "address" and not "date". Add an address field, then go to the settings page:`admin/structure/types/manage/client/fields/node.client.field_client_adresse` (for a content type named client and a field named field_client_adresse) the you be able to change the optional field under **Field overrides** at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you but I need to make them option if the payment option is of type Cheque only. Not always optional.